# Don't think I am interpreting JQuery post() response correctly

Tags: jquery, post

Writing a jquery function to check whether password user enters is already in use.
Using a blur event to send via post() value to a coldfusion page that returns 'ok' or `false`.
Using firebug, looks like am sending and receiving the expected data.

I'm guessing that perhaps my problem is in the return function. My first alert for resp gives correct. However, regardless the resp value (whether it is 'ok' or 'notok', I get the "else" option in the test.

Appreciate any thougts as what I wrong. (This is my first stackoverflow post, so hope I am doing this correctly!) Here is function that is called on the "ready". As I said, the jquery blur and the post seem to be correctly functioning. (I also used get() with same result.)

```
function setAjaxCk() {
$('#password').blur(function(){
    var myVal = $('#password').val();
    if (myVal.length < 1){
        return false;   
    }
    $.post("ajxTest.cfm",{myWord: myVal, myType: 'pw'},
          function(resp) {
              alert(resp);
              if(resp == 'ok'){
                alert('things are alright');  
              } else {
                alert('a problem here');  
              }
    });
    return false;
}); 
}
```

Comment: what does the server returns to you ?

Comment: Are myWord and myType already defined? Otherwise you have to put them in quotes.

Comment: in the jquery `post` doc.
dataTypeThe type of data expected from the server. Default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html). You should log your result in the console instead of alert so you can better see what is being returned.

Comment: @TimJoyce agreed, default doesn't go to JSON, so add json to your jQuery.post and then retry as in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the dataType of the post ? JSON i assume, can you try adding datatype = JSON in your jQuery.post and then re run your code ?

Comment: I must be missing something. Not sure about your datatype suggestion. Just sending 2 value params. my CF page expecting two text values and returning a text value.

Comment: to add datatype you do this: $.post("ajxTest.cfm",{myWord: myVal, myType: 'pw'},datatype: 'json',
          function(resp) {
              alert(resp);
              if(resp == 'ok'){
                alert('things are alright');  
              } else {
                alert('a problem here');  
              }
    });
    return false;
});

Comment: He is referring to the data being sent back from CF, not what you are sending. try `console.log(resp);` instead of `alert();` and tell us what you get

Comment: I get a js error if do the datatype as you have it (outside the curly braces). If add it as a third param (along with myVal, myType, etc), does not change any results.

Comment: my fault i gave you the incorrect format try this : $.post("ajxTest.cfm",{myWord: myVal, myType: 'pw'},"json", function(resp) { alert(resp); if(resp == 'ok'){ alert('things are alright'); } else { alert('a problem here'); } }); return false; });

Comment: Think I'm getting confused trying a number of things :-) Using dataType. My data returning is just text. Should I use that instead of 'json'?

Comment: :) okay lets do this one by one, 1 - > change datatype to dataType as figured by @TimJoyce then re run your code see what happens, and let us know

Comment: 1. should my dataType be 'json' or 'text'? 2. Where does the dataType param go? If after my curleys as noted, get js syntax error

Comment: according to sytax i saw for post, the dataType should be after the function: (if do that with 'json', seems to bypass function. With 'text', get same result)

    $.post("ajxTest.cfm",{myWord: myVal, myType: 'pw'},
     function(resp) {
     // alert(resp);
     console.log(resp);
      if(resp == 'ok'){
     alert('things are alright');  
      } else {
     alert('a problem here');  
      }
  },'json');

Comment: remove json and in your original code change your if like : if(resp.toString() == 'ok') { console.log('Got it working');}else {console.log('Nope not yet');}

Comment: @mprabhat : still get same inaccurate response. Regardless whether the post response is 'ok' or 'notok', I get the "Nope, not yet choice"

Comment: below are the supported format that returned data can be dataType   From the docs [at](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) The type of data expected from the server. Default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html), if you change your code to json then your server should also return json which I think is the correct way of handling this type of data

Comment: @mprabhat: cannot get my syntax correct for doing the json thing.

However: using resp.length, I find that the length is always 2 more than the actual length (or what it should be). ie: ok shows , and notok shows 7. Problem not seem to be in my CF plate, as get same result whether I do as a ColdFusion variable or just hardcode it.

Comment: if(jQuery.trim(resp.toString()) == 'ok') { console.log('Trailing space was the problem');} else { console.log('Nopes some other issue');} for json try this syntax $.post("ajxTest.cfm",{myWord: myVal, myType: 'pw'}, function(resp) { alert(resp); if(resp == 'ok'){ alert('things are alright'); } else { alert('a problem here'); } }); return false; }, "JSON");

Comment: @mprabhat : "WOW"; the jq trim thing seemed to take care of it! Gives the right length. Wonder what is being returned? I think doing all possible on the CF end to ensure only the text.

Did not go ahead and try the JSON addition. The trim alone seems to take care of things. Did try the JSON, but either that doesn't do anything or I am not getting it in right place for syntax.

Placing it at:
    },'JSON');
  return false;

seems only place not to cause JS error. (See my orig. code). But if use JSON there, seems to bypass my if/else check. 'text' works ok but still need the trim.

Comment: Glad it worked for you finally :), if you use JSON at both places client and server then you would be sending your response say in a variable named 'clientResponse' so in order to access that your if code should be if(resp.clientResponse == 'ok'), you can try this if you have time :).

Comment: @mprabhat
haven't used this forum before. Where mark your response about trim as answer?

Only place I see is the "1" at top of this comment series.

Answer (score 2):

put the code

```
 alert( Object.prototype.toString.apply(resp)  );
```

after it returns from the server and see its type.

also

try  `if(resp.toString() == 'ok'){`

Comment: did not seem to help. Same results

Comment: is the same as without the toString: ok or notok

Comment: @KeithDodd the alert is "ok" ?

Comment: @KeithDodd please upload a print screen of fiddler response

Answer (score 0):

I know this sounds elementary, but have you tried to trim your response to make sure there are no leading or trailing whitespace characters?

Comment: did a cfenableoutputonly setting and a trim. No help